# Reading from a mysql database and converting it to a string

Tags: c#

I need to read 4 columns from a mysql database and put it in a string.
I have already established a mysql connection and i can fill the database with c#.

The database consists of 1 table: files with 4 columns: 1 name 2 size 3 last edit 4 extension

I need to read 1 name 2 size 3 last edit 4 extension out of the database and convert them to strings.

Here is my code:

```
static void query()
{
    String sourcedatabase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"Database1"];
    String targetdatabase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"Database2"];
    var connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=******;password=******;database=" + sourcedatabase + ";");

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception )
    {
        logger("MySql connection error");
    }
}
```

Comment: and what exactly is your problem now?
--> What columns do you need to read, why do you have Target Database? What exactly do you want to do? What have you tried?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on `ExecuteNonQuery()`? Do you know what it does?

Comment: Where is your `query` defined? Also `.ExecuteNonQuery()` is for T-SQL. MySQL connection is not natively supported, you'll have to add a driver. Take a look at [Connect C# to MySQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL) on CodeProject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `MySqlDataReader`:

```
 MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Then loop round the returned results:

```
 while (dataReader.Read()) {
      var column1 = dataReader["column1"];
      var column2 = dataReader["column2"];
 }
```

Comment: This is for reading data from T-SQL database.

Comment: @maremp - T-SQL is just transact SQL, which is SQL Server.  This looks like MySQL.

Comment: He's using a MySQlDataReader, a MySQLCommand... Looks like MySQL to me...